# insert into with a Group By

Tags: mysql

I am trying to run the following query and put the results into a table called weekly_summary_activities.

```
Select 
  email, campaign, type, 
  year, week, business_comp, 
  activity, SUM(hours) 
FROM activity_log 
Group By email, campaign, project,
  business_comp, activity
```

The structure of weekly_summary_activities is

```
+--------+---------------+-------------+-------------------+------------+------+---------+----------+----------------+
|     #  |     Name      |    Type     |     Collation     | Attributes | Null | Default | Comments |     Extra      |
+--------+---------------+-------------+-------------------+------------+------+---------+----------+----------------+
|      1 | idPrimary     | tinyint(4)  |                   |            | No   | None    |          | AUTO_INCREMENT |
|      2 | email         | varchar(30) | latin1_swedish_ci |            | No   | None    |          |                |
|      3 | campaign      | varchar(30) | latin1_swedish_ci |            | No   | None    |          |                |
|      4 | type          | varchar(3)  | latin1_swedish_ci |            | No   | None    |          |                |
|      5 | year          | varchar(4)  | latin1_swedish_ci |            | No   | None    |          |                |
|      6 | week          | int(3)      |                   |            | No   | None    |          |                |
|      7 | business_comp | varchar(30) | latin1_swedish_ci |            | No   | None    |          |                |
|      8 | project       | varchar(30) | latin1_swedish_ci |            | No   | None    |          |                |
|      9 | activity      | varchar(30) | latin1_swedish_ci |            | No   | None    |          |                |
|     10 | hours         | int(8)      |                   |            | No   | None    |          |                |
+--------+---------------+-------------+-------------------+------------+------+---------+----------+----------------+
```

I have tried:

```
INSERT INTO weekly_summary_activities 
SELECT email, 
       campaign, 
       type, 
       year, 
       week, 
       business_comp, 
       activity, 
       Sum(hours) 
FROM   activity_log 
GROUP  BY email, 
          campaign, 
          project, 
          business_comp, 
          activity
```

but I get an error "#1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1". What am I doing wrong? It seems that it is just the insert into that doesn't work. I can run the query (wo the insert) in phpMyAdminSQL's SQL tab and that seems to work.

Comment: The error message means you don't have enough column values. Your table has 10 columns, the SELECT statement has 8 columns. Either add two more columns to the SELECT statement or explicitly specify the column names as part of the insert statement.

Comment: Your current query is not even valid because you are selecting non aggregate columns.  The immediate problem can be fixed by specifying the columns you want to target for insertion.

Comment: Thx. I changed it to: insert into Select id, email, campaign, type, year, week, business_comp, project, activity, SUM(hours) FROM activity_log Group By email, campaign, project,business_comp, activity. This fails with #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Select id, email, campaign, type, year, week, business_comp, project, activity, ' at line 1. id is an autoincrement. So I don't have a value to insert in that field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should specify column in the insert into clause, like :

```
INSERT INTO weekly_summary_activities (email, campaign, type, year, week, business_comp, activity, hours)
SELECT email, campaign, type, year, week, business_comp, activity, SUM(hours) 
FROM activity_log
GROUP BY email, campaign, project, business_comp, activity
```

You got the issue because the table contains an Id column.  Table have more columns than the insert clause.

Comment: I tried your code above. I am getting Error Number: 1062</p><p>Duplicate entry '127' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: Pasting this directly into SQL tab I get: #1467 - Failed to read auto-increment value from storage engine

Comment: seems like the field hours gets the sum effortlessly just because it is summed in the select! +